# Format a float with minimum required number of decimal places

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting, floating-point-precision

I want to format a float with the minimum number of decimal places required to reproduce it.

PHP has a `number_format()` function for rendering a number with a specified number of decimal places. However, if I use it to format 0.1 with a very high number of decimals, I get:

```
print rtrim(number_format(0.1, 1000, '.', ''), '0');
// 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Since `(float)"0.1" === 0.1`, those extra `55511151...` decimals after position 16 are useless.

I can use a loop, like this:

```
function format_float($float) {
    $decimals = 1;
    do {
        $result = number_format($float, $decimals, '.', '');
        $decimals++;
    } while ((float)$result !== $float);
    return $result;
}

print format_float(0.1) . "\n"; // 0.1
print format_float(1/3) . "\n"; // 0.3333333333333333
print format_float(1E-50) . "\n"; // 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

But surely there is a simpler and more efficient way?

Comment: Probably round() help in your case?

Comment: @VladimirGilevich I don't see how that's related. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Those extra decimal places may be useless, but they are [very much real](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: @Jesse, just first what I thinking was round(), but probably it is not better variant.  But if you add next code in your loop before "$decimals++;":  `$rounded = floor($float * pow(10, $decimals)) / pow(10, $decimals); if ($rounded > 0 && $result == $rounded) { break;}` Probably it will give you closer results to that you need...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know they're real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
function format_float($num) {
    $dec = $num == 0 ? 0 : ceil(-log10(abs($num)));
    $dec = max(1, $dec + 15 /* magic number */);
    $res = number_format($num, $dec, '.', '');

    // sometimes we need one more decimal
    if ((float)$res !== $num) {
        $res = number_format($num, $dec + 1, '.', '');
    }

    list($l, $r) = explode('.', $res, 2);
    return "$l." . (rtrim($r) ?: '0');
}
```

It assumes the number of decimals needed will be `15 - log10($num)` or `16 - log10($num)`, which seems to hold in practice according to my testing. It's at least more efficient than my brute force loop.

Answer (score 1):

Correctly printing the minimal number of decimal digits of a binary floating point number is a *very* complicated endeavour. The current state-of-the-art are the [grisu family of algorithms](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf). For a good explanation of the problems involved, see the classic paper by [Steele and White](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf).

Comment: Does my brute force little loop correctly do this "very complicated endeavour"? Or is simply that all the more efficient ways are much more complicated?

Comment: I was perhaps a bit brusk: your methods does actually do it correctly (albeit inefficiently, but this is probably not a huge problem unless you're repeating it millions of times). What you shouldn't do is what Vladimir suggested: multiply or divide by powers of 10, then round, as this introduces floating point rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

Code from @Jesse didn't work for me, so build this:

```
function formatFloat(float $num, int $dec = 0) : string {

    // format to maximum decimal places, and make positive
    $abs = number_format(abs($num), 17, '.', '');

    // is it less than 0?
    if (!floor($abs)) {

        // look through each number until we find one that is not 0
        foreach (str_split(substr($abs, 2)) AS $i => $item) {
            if ($item) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // add defined decimal places
        $dec += $i + 1;
    }

    // format the output
    return number_format($num, $dec);
}
```

It can handle numbers larger than one, negative numbers, and enables you to specify how many decimal places to format the float to after the first significant number is found. It also performs better.